# Is there support for h2o4gpu for deeplearning in python?

Tags: python, h2o

Can you please let me know if there's support for h2o4gpu on AWS EC2 instance to generate deep learning models? If yes, then are there any references for installation and examples?

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked to see if this is available? http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o4gpu/latest-stable/h2o4gpu-py-docs/html/intro.html

Comment: Go to h2o.ai's website, and if it doesn't say there, contact their support. You could post and accept a self-answer here when you find out.

Comment: there are install instructions here too: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o4gpu/blob/master/README.md